# Interpretation of Bayes Factor

Tags: bayesian

I'm slightly confused with the interpretation of the Bayes factor.

Let's say `ttestBF(diffScores, nullInterval=c(0,Inf))` outputs a bayes factor of `0.15`. Is this considered weak or substantial evidence for H1?

In this [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4114196/) there is a sentence that reads

> There is strong evidence for the alternative (B much greater than 1);
> there is strong evidence for the null (B close to 0); and the evidence
> is insensitive (B close to 1).

0.15 is closer to zero so I would say strong evidence for the null

Later, however, the author writes

> A Bayes factor greater than 3 or else less than 1/3 represents
> substantial evidence

0.15 is less than 1/3, so I would say this represents substantial evidence.

So which of the interpretations is correct?

Comment: The bar is at one, that is a Bayes factor of $1$ is agnostic about either model. Below $1$, it starts bringing evidence in favour of the marginal in the denominator indeed. I would however suggest caution about this Jeffreys scale by calibrating the Bayes factor running simulations under both models or hypotheses. And suggest you make the question more self contained as external links do not live forever.

Comment: Thanks @Xi'an, I'm relatively new to Bayes Factor, can you show me how to run a simple simulation on a data set like the sleep data?

Answer (score 1):

The Bayes factor tells us how to update our relative belief in theory $H_1$ versus theory $H_0$
$$
\text{Relative belief after data}  = \text{Bayes factor} \times \text{Relative belief before data}
$$
A Bayes factor

- $B < 1$ indicates that $H_0$ (i.e., hypothesis in the denominator) becomes relatively more plausible after data than it was before
- $B = 1$ indicates no change
- $B > 1$ indicates that $H_1$ (i.e., hypothesis in the numerator) becomes relatively more plausible after data than it was before

Ascribing qualitative meanings to the magnitude of $B$, i.e., judging what constitutes strong or weak evidence is to some degree arbitrary. Popular conventions exist, though, e.g., the Jeffreys' scale.